# How to install metasploit and armitage in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I've a problem with Armitage and Metasploit. I tried this commands to install them

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then a pasted this and saved the list

```
deb http://
http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib

deb http://
security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://
http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://
security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib
```

Then I used

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install armitage
```

And everything finished ok. Armitage worked fine and so did metasploit but then I don't know what have I done and I couldn't start them again so I tried to update and install them again but I got this problem

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
armitage is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-ar kde-l10n-engb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 310 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up metasploit (4.11.2-2015051401-1kali0) ...
 * Starting Metasploit rpc server prosvc                                                                                 [ OK ] 
 * Starting Metasploit web server thin                                                                                          /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.9/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/ui/scripts/ctl.rb:30:in `start_thin'
    from /opt/metasploit/apps/pro/ui/scripts/ctl.rb:47:in `<main>'
invoke-rc.d: initscript metasploit, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package metasploit (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of armitage:
 armitage depends on metasploit; however:
  Package metasploit is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package armitage (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 metasploit
 armitage
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix it?

Note: my linux dist is Ubuntu 14.0.4 64 bit

Comment: It is not recommend to mix repositories.

Comment: Reinstall from scratch.  The Kali repos are Debian and not Ubuntu and mixing repositories from multiple distros will usually always trash your system (unless you use apt pinning correctly)

Answer (score 4):

First thing first, as people already have said, do not mix repos!

So first reinstall Ubuntu, and then here is a link for armitage.

http://www.fastandeasyhacking.com/download/ <-- It's their website
and download the .tgz version as it's the linux one.

Before you do anything, install Java

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Open it up and inside is a file called "armitage", open up a terminal and go to the section where the folder is located. And type `./armitage`

This should run the program.

**For metasploit, you can download it [from my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w43liuyq2mopd3i/metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run?dl=0).**

To install it, just cd into the folder and run

```
chmod +x metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run
```

and then

```
./metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run
```

You might need to have sudo privileges for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use packages from of other distros, but I found a nice tutorial on how to install them on Debian and Ubuntu that I really must recommend:
[http://www.darkoperator.com/](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/)

There is also a katoolin script on github here:

https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin

USE THIS WITH CAUTION! again it is **not** recommended to use ANY reposetories from other distros