# Problem installing armitage

Tags: metasploit

When installing armitage, after downloading and extracting, I wrote:

```
sudo sh -c "echo java -jar /opt/armitage/armitage.jar \$\* > /opt/armitage/armitage"
```

And to that I got:

```
sh: 1: cannot create /opt/armitage/armitage/: Is a directory
```

Anyone know what the issue is here?
Thanks!

Comment: What it says, there's already a directory named `armitage` in `/opt/armitage/`, so you can't create a file of the same name. Which instructions are you following?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/887873/692175

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to see if /opt/armitage/armitage/ has any content. If the directory is empty, you may wish to delete the directory and rerun the command.

```
sudo sh -c "echo java -jar /opt/armitage/armitage.jar \$\* > /opt/armitage/armitage"
```

That command wants to create the directory /opt/armitage/armitage .  Which already exists.

If the directory has content, you may place a tailing slash,

```
sudo sh -c "echo java -jar /opt/armitage/armitage.jar \$\* > /opt/armitage/armitage/"
```

Then it will create the structure: /opt/armitage/armitage/armitage

Answer (score 0):

I just installed armitage. I see what made a problem for me. When I run the command

```
sudo sh -c "echo java -jar /opt/armitage/armitage.jar \$\* > /opt/armitage/armitage"
```

Run the command BEFORE you make the sym-links:
If you run the command AFTER you make the sym-links, will get an error. 
I got the same error as you when I made the sym-links in the order shown. I deleted the sym-link and run the command it installed fine. Then I made the sym-links